# Question on FIDE Rating List Submission

Tags: rules, learning, fide, rating

I am playing in a tournament on the 19th-20th of this month and I have a question regarding FIDE rating change for the end of the month when the new list is published.

I have done very well in some tournaments at the start of the month and I am going to gain around 100+ elo based on some calculations I have done for the list coming out at the start of the September month. Let's just say for simplicity I am 1700 FIDE and that means I will be 1800 FIDE next month assuming I don't play any more tournaments.

The issue is however the tournament organizer has a tendency to send in the results of the tournament late and way into the next month's list, so I was wondering if the rating change would be based off the previous month's list when the games were played. In simpler words if the tournament results come in for next month will they count as if I was 1700 FIDE originally or when I become 1800 FIDE.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if the rating change would be based off the previous month's list when the games were played

Ratings are calculated according to when the results are submitted to FIDE not when the games were played. Hence games which were played in August but were not submitted to FIDE until September will be rated using September ratings not August. To do otherwise would require that previous rating lists be invalidated and ratings recalculated.

Comment: I have seen players who had huge spikes in 2 months having their gains calculated using the rating of 1st month, also bypassing k factor rules. So I'm still confused but I might be missing something here

Comment: After doing a bit of research I agree with you here. I think that FIDE takes the rating of the previous month into their report in the RO section. An example was a player rated 1983 lost 4 rating points dropping to 1979, however because the tournament was turned in a month later it took the previous month's calculations. This was somewhat old statistics however so it would be great if someone can verify based off the new rules.